# Improper nodes and equilibrium points of a linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $a$ constant, I want to find all $a$ such that the equilibrium solution for the system below is an improper node.

I don't really know what to do. I know proper and improper nodes occur when eigenvalues are real and repeated, but my book doesn't say how to tell if, in this case, which of the two it is (improper or proper). Also, I don't really understand how a solution can be an improper node *at a point* (the equilibrium point, as the question says). I thought that what the stability of a system was and the type of critical point depended on the eigenvalues and not on the equilibrium solution.

$x' = \begin{bmatrix}-4 & -3\\3 & a\end{bmatrix} x$

Comment: @Moo I'm not having trouble finding the eigenvalues. I'm having trouble with how to tell whether something is an improper node (from a proper node) and the other point I made in my question.

Comment: @Moo oh I was confused because my book says that when you have one eigenvalue of multiplicity two it is a proper *or* improper node. So I thought there must be some further distinction. Well the answer is just when $a^2 + 8a - 20$ = 0.

Comment: @Moo Well if the eigenvalues are the same then they have the same sign! So I still wouldn't be able to differentiate b/t a proper and improper node without a further condition.